# Java - Sort an array with Extreme Minimum or maximum values

Tags: java, sorting

I want to sort my float array by alternating maximum and minimum value. 
I.e. largest, smallest, next largest, next smallest etc.

For example I have follwing values in my Arraylist:

```
[1.22 ,2.55 ,9.88 ,7.23 ,8.22]
```

I would like to get it sorted like:

```
[9.88, 1.22 ,8.22 ,2.55 ,7.23]
```

Currently i am sorting the values in decessending order using following code,

```
Collections.sort(characterPairs, new Comparator<Pair<String, Double>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Pair<String, Double> o1, Pair<String, Double> o2) {
            if(o1.second>o2.second)
                return -1;
            if(o1.second<o2.second)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: no clue what you're asking here. You have something and you want something. Please be clear

Comment: You want to alternate maximum and minimum, right? Largest, smallest, next largest, next smallest, etc. Is that it?

Comment: @khelwood exactly

Comment: @TimCastelijns i am looking for exactly what khelwood stated.

Comment: Sort your array (of size n) then create a resulting array with the items n, 0, n-1, 1, n-2, 2, ....

Answer (score 2):

I got it done with following code, thanks to everyone for your time.

```
  Collections.sort(characterPairs, new Comparator<Pair<String, Double>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Pair<String, Double> o1, Pair<String, Double> o2) {
            double n1,n2;
            if(o1.second<0.50)  // 0.50 is the posible mean value
                n1=1-o1.second; // 1 is the maximum posible value
            else
                n1=o1.second;
            if(o2.second<0.50) // 0.50 is the posible mean value
                n2=1-o2.second; // 1 is the maximum posible value
            else
                n2=o2.second;

            if(n1>n2)
                return -1;
            if(n1<n2)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Here If value is small then mean value (50%) I subtract it from maximum possible value and then sort it descendingly. (subtracted value is only used to sort the actual value.)

So if I have these values in an array

```
[0.11,0.34,0.99,0.85,0.21]
```

It will be sorted as

```
[ 0.99 , 0.11 (0.89) , 0.85 , 0.21 (0.79) , 0.34 (0.66)]
```

- (value) is the subtracted value that was used to sort it.

Comment: It's a wrong solution, try with this [0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49, 0.65]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is too complex to try to resolve it with a simple comparator, You will need two steps, first the regular sort and the second step is an expecial merge.

```
    // first step:
    Collections.sort(characterPairs, (o1, o2) -> {
        return Double.compare(o1.second, o2.second);
    });

    // second step:
    List<Pair<String, Double>> result = new ArrayList<>(characterPairs.size());
    while (!characterPairs.isEmpty()){
        result.add(characterPairs.remove(characterPairs.size() -1));
        if (!characterPairs.isEmpty()) {
            result.add(characterPairs.remove(0));
        }
    }
    characterPairs = result;
```